# Adding admin link to Appearance via admin_menu, adds link to theme details modal

Tags: admin-menu

When you use `admin_menu` hook to add a navigation item to the Appearances section in the admin menu it will also add that link to the modal that pops up when you click "Theme Details", unfortunately it does not add the link correctly, it links to `themes.php?page={new_link}`

```
function add_theme_link_into_appearnace_menu() {
  global $submenu;
  $permalink = admin_url( 'admin.php?page=theme-settings', 'https' );
  $submenu['themes.php'][0] = array( 'theme Settings', 'manage_options', $permalink );
}
add_action('admin_menu', 'add_theme_link_into_appearnace_menu');
```

Am I missing a setting somewhere to make this link go to the proper url, as when clicking through it just goes to a page that doesn't exist

see image showing the tooltip (mouse hovered over the button in the theme modal).

[image: Shows clip of theme details modal with url tooltip]

*Yes, I know it says wp.com, that's my local test environment settings*

Comment: that's not how new menus are normally added to the admin menu, is there a particular reason you did it by modifying global variables instead of using the normal function like the official docs mention? And how did you implement your theme settings page without using those functions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have added this to my admin.js file (pulled into admin pages within the theme)

```
$('#tmpl-theme-single').html($('#tmpl-theme-single').html().replace('themes.php?page=', '');
```

This seems a little hacky to me, I am sure there is a possible solution within the WordPress codebase but I can't find it.  If someone comes up with a better solution I will move the resolution to you

Answer (score 0):

That's not how you add submenus to the appearance menu, or how you create settings pages for themes.

Adding a submenu involves either `add_submenu_page` which lets you add submenus to any menu item, or the helper function `add_theme_page` which is for the appearance menu.

Here's one of the examples from the official documentation:

```php
function add_test_theme_page() {
    add_theme_page( 'Theme Title Settings', 'Theme Menu Settings', 'edit_theme_options', 'test-theme-options', 'theme_option_page' );
}
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'add_test_theme_page' );

function theme_option_page() {
    echo 'This is a test theme options page!';
}
```

Further reading:

- https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_theme_page/
- https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_submenu_page/

Comment: I have the options page already, and its navigation is created, I wanted to add a link to it under the "Appearances" menu because that is where the theme is selected and the "Customizer" link is.  As I am not using the customizer I want to have a link to the theme settings (different nav menu) in the Appearances dropover menu.  Which is exactly where I wanted it.  What I didn't expect was the new button created in the theme modal and it being linked incorrectly, which is what my question is.  How do I link that correctly in the modal, or barring that how do I remove it from the modal